# How to use jackson instead of JdkSerializationRedisSerializer in spring

Tags: java, spring, redis, jackson

I'm using redis in one of my java apps and I'm serializing a list of objects to be stored in Redis. However, I noticed that using the RedisTemplate would use the JdkSerializationRedisSerializer. Instead, I'd like to use Jackson to serialize since I believe it is better for speed. How would I go about configuring my RedisTemplate to use Jackson instead?

For clarification, this is how I'm configuring my RedisTemplate:

```
@Override
protected RedisConfiguration getRedisConfiguration() {
    return redisConfiguration;
}

@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> getRedisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    return template;
}
```

Comment: you can call setKeySerializer method or setValueSerializer method

Comment: @Frank.Dai could you include an example of how I would do that? thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

like this,

```
@Bean
public RedisTemplate<String, Object> getRedisTemplate() {
    RedisTemplate<String, Object> template = new RedisTemplate<>();
    Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer jrs = new Jackson2JsonRedisSerializer(String.class);
    template.setKeySerializer(jrs);
    template.setConnectionFactory(jedisConnectionFactory());
    return template;
}
```

and, I suggest you read this document
https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:template